# Primefaces 3.4.1 does not POST with a form inside a dialog

Tags: jsf, primefaces

EDIT: the question does not have an answer with the linked resource, but I solved. I'll post the solution.

I'm working on a project that uses Primefaces 3.4.1 (and no, I can't update it).

I created a dialog with some inputs. The method is invoked, but the inputs are not populated in the bean. This does not happen in a "normal" form.

This is the simplified code:

browse.xhtml:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      template="../layout/template.xhtml">
      
      <ui:define name="body">
          <p:dialog 
              id="dialog" 
              visible="#{bean.getDialogVisible()}" 
              modal="true"
          >
              <h:form id="form">
                  <p:inputText 
                      id="x" 
                      styleClass="Form-input" 
                      value="#{bean.x}"
                  />
                  <p:commandButton 
                      value="submit" 
                      action="#{bean.submit()}"
                      immediate="true"
                  ></p:commandButton>
              </h:form>
          </p:dialog>
      </ui:define>
</ui:composition>
```

Bean.java:

```
@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class Bean {
    private String x;
    private boolean isDialogVisible;

    public String getX() {
        return x;
    }

    public void setX(String x) {
        this.x = x;
    }

    public boolean isDialogVisible() {
        return isDialogVisible;
    }

    public void setDialogVisible(boolean isDialogVisible) {
        this.isDialogVisible = isDialogVisible;
    }
    
    public boolean getDialogVisible() {
        boolean res = this.isDialogVisible();
        this.setDialogVisible(false);
        return res;
    }
    
    public void submit() {
        logger.info(this.x);
    }
}
```

In loggind and during debugging, `x` is always `null` inside the method `submit()`.

PS: note that the `commandButton` does not invoke `submit()` at all, if `immediate="true"` or `ajax="false"` are not specified.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I removed `immediate="true"` and added `process="@form"` to the `p:commandButton` and now it works.